# MySQL Update from mm/dd/YY h:i:s A to YY-mm-dd H-i-s

Tags: mysql, datetime

I recently change the data type of my field from varchar to datetime, but before I did that, I made a copy of it first because the content will reset to this value 000-00-00 00-00-00

And now, I am trying to update the datetime field of my table.

Here's what I did

```
UPDATE table
INNER JOIN copyOfTable ON (table.logID = copyOfTable.logID)
SET table.date =  DATE(STR_TO_DATE(copyOfTable.date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

The result goes something like this

```
YYYY-mm-dd 00-00-00
2013-08-02 00-00-00
```

I also tried

```
SET table.date =  DATE(STR_TO_DATE(copyOfTable.date, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s'))
```

and the result remains the same.

What I want is to copy the time also (hh:ii:ss)

```
so that the total format of time is (YY-mm-dd hh-ii-ss)
```

The format of time from table 'copyOfTable' is (mm/dd/yy h:i:s A)

How to do this guys?

Comment: try again with h in lower case `'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s'`

Comment: @zzlalani yup I already did that, but didn't works

Comment: @zzlalani not working, it gives me a null result

Answer (score 2):

IMHO

1. don't wrap `STR_TO_DATE()` into `DATE()` if you need time portion of your datetime values to be preserved
2. your format string should be `'%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s %p'`

According to you

> The format of time from table 'copyOfTable' is (mm/dd/yy h:i:s A)

so if I understand correctly your values in `copyOfTable` look like `08/01/13 04:08:12 AM`

Here is an example

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('08/01/13 04:08:12 AM', '%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s %p') new_date
```

Output:

```
|                      NEW_DATE |
---------------------------------
| August, 01 2013 04:08:12+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/17519)** demo

Comment: thanks @peterm, from your answer it lead me to the right answer. I removed the DATE so that STR_TO_DATE is not wrap anymore. Then it works